# Invisible Data Binding

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to keep up with essentially a state machine where I have several controls in a Panel. What I've done is setup a Boolean property on the form that is bound to a CheckBox. Setting up the data bindings for the controls that I want to be visible when the property is True was simple:

```
Public Property IsCalibration As Boolean = True

Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    CheckBoxIsCalibration.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Checked", Me, "IsCalibration", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, False))
    ButtonStartCalibration.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Visible", Me, "IsCalibration", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, False))
    ButtonSave.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Visible", Me, "IsCalibration", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, False))
    LabelProductionNumber.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Visible", Me, "IsCalibration", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, False))
    TextBoxProductionNumber.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Visible", Me, "IsCalibration", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, False))
    LabelEngageNumber.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Visible", Me, "IsCalibration", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, False))
    TextBoxEngageNumber.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Visible", Me, "IsCalibration", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, False))
    TextBoxEngageNumber.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Visible", Me, "IsCalibration", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, False))
End Sub
```

But how do I setup the data bindings for the controls that I want to be hidden when IsCalibration is False? Something similar to an "Invisible" data binding.

I know that one alternative is to setup an overridable sub that gets called when the IsCalibration property is changed, which invokes an event, which could set the value of a separate property called *IsNotCalibration* to the opposite of what *IsCalibration* is so that I could bind the other controls to that IsNotCalibration property. But I don't  like this solution, it seems like an unnecessary measure just to set what is effectively an "Invisible" effect.

Also as a side note, while I'm using VB.NET I am more than comfortable with C# solutions as they're basically the same language with a different syntax flavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to handle the `Format` and `Parse` events of the `Binding` objects and invert the values.  I just added two `Buttons`, two `TextBoxes` and a `CheckBox` to a form and did this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim normalBinding1 = Button1.DataBindings.Add("Visible", CheckBox1, "Checked")
    Dim normalBinding2 = TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Visible", CheckBox1, "Checked")

    Dim inverseBinding1 = Button2.DataBindings.Add("Visible", CheckBox1, "Checked")
    Dim inverseBinding2 = TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Visible", CheckBox1, "Checked")

    With inverseBinding1
        AddHandler .Format, AddressOf InvertBinding
        AddHandler .Parse, AddressOf InvertBinding
    End With

    With inverseBinding2
        AddHandler .Format, AddressOf InvertBinding
        AddHandler .Parse, AddressOf InvertBinding
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub InvertBinding(sender As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs)
    e.Value = Not CBool(e.Value)
End Sub
```

When I checked the `CheckBox`, only `Buton1` and `TextBox1` were visible and, when I unchecked it, only `Button2` and `TextBox2` were visible.

Here's some shorter but functionally equivalent code:

```
Private WithEvents inverseBinding1 As Binding
Private WithEvents inverseBinding2 As Binding

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Button1.DataBindings.Add("Visible", CheckBox1, "Checked")
    TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Visible", CheckBox1, "Checked")

    inverseBinding1 = Button2.DataBindings.Add("Visible", CheckBox1, "Checked")
    inverseBinding2 = TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Visible", CheckBox1, "Checked")
End Sub

Private Sub InvertBinding(sender As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs) Handles inverseBinding1.Format,
                                                                           inverseBinding1.Parse,
                                                                           inverseBinding2.Format,
                                                                           inverseBinding2.Parse
    e.Value = Not CBool(e.Value)
End Sub
```